# Probability that a man waits less than five minutes for a bus

Tags: probability-theory

Buses arrive at ten minute intervals starting at noon. A man arrives at the bus stop at a random time $X$ minutes after noon, where $X$ has the CDF $F_X(x)$:

\begin{cases} 
      0 & x< 0 \\
      \frac{x}{60} & 0\leq x\leq 60 \\
      1 & 60> x 
\end{cases}

What is the probability that he waits less than five minutes for a bus?

This implies that his time of arrival is uniformly distributed. Will the result be simply $5/60$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, note that the PDF is:
$$f_X(x)=\frac{d}{dx} F_X(x)=\frac{1}{60}, 0\le x\le 60.$$
Hence, the required probability is:
$$P(5<x<10)+P(15<x<20)+P(25<x<30)+\\
P(35<x<40)+P(45<x<50)+P(55<x<60)=\\
6\int_5^{10} \frac1{60}dx=6\cdot \frac{5}{60}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 2):

Given that the buses arrive every $10$ minutes, the buses arrive $6$ times within an hour time.

The man arrives uniformly at any minute within an hour, so it is also uniform within a $10$-minute interval. The probability he waits for less than $5$ minutes is therefore $1/2$.